# Are the storm cones introduced by Robert Fitzroy still in use?

Tags: weather-forecasting, storms

In 1860 or so, following the tragic wreck of the *Royal Charter* with the loss of over 400 lives, storm cones were installed in many UK ports, under the direction of Admiral Fitzroy, head of the government's forerunner of the modern Meteorological Office, to warn mariners of expected gales. My question is, please, are these storm cones still in use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A page in the book *[Come Rain or Shine, A Weather Miscellany](https://books.google.com/books?id=sxAgCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT143&ots=Ozu4gOVcAe&dq=fitzroy%20storm%20warning%20cone&pg=PT143#v=onepage&q=fitzroy%20storm%20warning%20cone&f=false)* states that the cones were discontinued on June 1, 1984, due to their being superseded by radio broadcasts and other methods.

Comment: Thanks you, Daniel, for that answer and very useful reference, Harry